# How to assign a date value to **Nullable<System.DateTime>** property (ASP.NET MVC4)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, initialization

Problem: initialize a `DateTime` variable with a date value (by hardcoding).

Value: 
`2014-03-31`

Variable: 
`public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeStart { get; set; }`

Attempt (failed):
`Course.TimeEnd = (DateTime?)"2014-03-31";`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `DateTime` object, not a `string`.  Thus, you would do this:

```
Course.TimeEnd = new DateTime(2014, 3, 31);
```